# Why has the October 2023 release of the Arch Linux ISO been delayed?

Tags: arch-linux, lsb-release

Here are the releases of Arch Linux in the last months before this month:

- `2023-05-03`
- `2023-06-01`
- `2023-07-01`
- `2023-08-01`
- `2023-09-01`

As we can see, ISO releases were published on the first day of each month, or a few days later.

But for the last release, it took 2 weeks and it was published in October 14<sup>th</sup>: `2023-10-14`

What caused the delay of this particular release?

Source: https://archlinux.org/releng/releases/

Comment: Surprising, the [commit log](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/archiso/-/commits/master) for the ISO shows that it was done Sep 29, 2023

Comment: @pipe It looks like this commit is about the tool that generate the ISO, not the `2023-10-14` release directly. I would be interested in knowing how Arch Linux releases are created, it would help to answer to the original question.

Comment: It's important to note that these are just releases of the iso images. The arch distribution itself is not a versioned thing - it's a rolling release thing. So if you are looking for rule-based release cycles, it's probably not the right place to look. These image releases serve no other purpose than to allow users to install a system without instantly having to upgrade *all* their packages. So, frankly, it's not something I'd put a high priority on, and maybe some automation script broke, and nobody noticed. You should honestly ask the arch community on chat or mail, not us.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is something only the Arch developers can answer, and not a general question about Unix or Linux.

Comment: Sorry, but this really can only be answered by the developers, we can't help you here. I would ask on the [Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/) instead.